# Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA' in /var/www/laravel/config/database.php on line 68

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

After setting up a docker container with laravel, I am getting the following error in the browser:

`Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA' in /var/www/laravel/config/database.php on line 68`

Content of this line:

```
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('DB_MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA', ''),
```

This is a Debian official image from PHP5, including php5-mysql (which based on the Debian page https://packages.debian.org/jessie/php5-mysql includes php commons 5.6.30 which should be enough if I am correct) the complete Dockerfile can be found here https://github.com/lechmigdal/laravel-mysql-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile.

Are there any other packages that I need to include or additional configuration required?

Comment: Show 68th line of the `config/database.php` file please.

Comment: Laravel requires at least PHP >= 5.6.4

Comment: Added line 68. Laravel works like a dream, the problem is only with the PDO :(

Comment: @LechMigdal, what line you have added? Please explain.. I have the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: **Enable the pdo_mysql extension** in *php.ini* file

In PHP 7.2.10 :

1. open the php-folder/**php.ini** file
2. search for *"**extension=pdo_mysql**"* line
3. remove the **semicolon(;)** before the line ( uncomment the line)
4. or paste ***extension=pdo_mysql*** if not present

In some lower versions of php, the line may appear as

- extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll on Windows
- extension=php_pdo_mysql.so on Linux/Mac

Step 2:
**Serve** your application

If running your application shows error "No application encryption key has been specified.", Then follow Step 3 and then serve again.

Step 3: (optional)
**Generate APP KEY** using artisan for your application

```
your-project-folder>php artisan key:generate
```

That should solve your problem.